# Forces create fields or fields create forces?

Tags: forces, field-theory, noethers-theorem

I was always taught that gravity, static electricity etc forces cause the creation of the fields associated with them. But Noether's Theorem says that forces are created due to fields & not vice versa. Explanation?

Comment: Reference to claim? Page?

Answer (score 1):

Fields are the strength of a force at any distance from the source.

For a point electrical source (electron) and with no other sources in the vicinity, they are only related by a coefficient as a function of distance.

It is important to point out at this point that in this *single source case*, the force remains a mathematical construct. There is no force acting because there is no object of action ( test specimen, other electron).